# How to change if constructs in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am working in an assignment for my intro to programming class. 
Here is what my professor is asking:

Change the program without adding another loop, so it determines if the grade entered is valid, and if not, display an error message and keep asking until a valid grade is entered. Change the program, so it counts how many grades scored A, B, C, D, and F. Do NOT use stacked if or if-else constructs. Do NOT use the else if format. Output a table of the count of how many there are for each letter grade.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Ask the user to enter 10 test scores.
The pass mark is 70%.
Calculate the average score, and count how many
of the students have passed the test.
*/

#define SCORES_COUNT 10
#define BAD_SCORE 60
#define PASSING_SCORE 70
#define GOOD_SCORE 80
#define EXCELLENT_SCORE 90

int main()
{
    int scores[SCORES_COUNT];
    int i, sum = 0, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0, sum4 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_COUNT; i++)
        {
        printf("Enter score for student %i: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", &scores[i]);
        if (scores[i] > 100 || scores[i] < 0)
            {
            printf("\n\tERROR: Invalid number! Enter a score above zero and below one hundred!\n\n");
            printf("Enter score for student %i: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%i", &scores[i]);
            }
        }

    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_COUNT; i++)
    {   
        if (scores[i] >= EXCELLENT_SCORE)
        {
            sum++;
        }
        if (scores[i] >= GOOD_SCORE && scores[i] < EXCELLENT_SCORE)
        {
            sum1++;
        }
        if (scores[i] >= PASSING_SCORE && scores[i] < GOOD_SCORE)
        {
            sum2++;
        }
        if (scores[i] >= BAD_SCORE && scores[i] < PASSING_SCORE)
        {
            sum3++;
        }
        if (scores[i] < BAD_SCORE)
        {
            sum4++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nGrades Distribution\n");
    printf("\nA:  %i", sum);
    printf("\nB:  %i", sum1);
    printf("\nC:  %i", sum2);
    printf("\nD:  %i", sum3);
    printf("\nF:  %i\n", sum4);

    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

The program works fine, but my teacher told me to not use stacked if or if-else constructs. And since I am a beginner that is the only way I know how to do it.

Can somebody please tell me how can I change all the if constructs, or how can I have the same result without using any if constructs?

Comment: use switch statement?

Comment: "Keep asking until valid" and "no new loop" makes this non-trivial.

Comment: Maybe use arrays to count the numbers at each grade level.  Put the score range for each grade into an array of structures, or a set of arrays if you've not covered structures yet (which seems probable).  Maybe `int grade_lo[] = { 0, BAD_SCORE, PASSING_SCORE, … };` and `int grade_hi[] = { BAD_SCORE, PASSING_SCORE, … };` and so on.  You might give the letter grades in an array too, and the counts for each grade, and so on.

Comment: if you cant make another input loop then you need to change the existing input loop to only increment i when the input is correct

Comment: Why didn't you use a suffix on plain `sum` for consistency?  It puzzles me when people aren't consistent.  Indeed, `sumA` .. `sumF` might have been good choices.